# SQLSTATE[HY000] Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `laravel`.`projects` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed")

I get the above error when I migrate my projects table and try to join three tables which:

1. A user has many products, and products have their own id.
2. A product has many projects, and projects have their own id.

**User table (user.php)**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
        $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Product table (product.php)**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('detail');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('logo');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Project table (project.php)**

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // $table->('id');
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('detail', 500)->nullable();
    $table->string('color', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('image', 22)->nullable();
    $table->string('logo', 22)->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
});
```

**User model**

```
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}

public function getProject()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
}
```

**Product model**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'detail', 'image', 'color', 'logo', 'user_id'
];

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Project model**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'detail', 'image','color','logo','user_id'
];

public function getUser(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I also need help to make my model work.

Comment: change user table  $table->id(); to $table->bigIncrements('id');

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`projects` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Comment: after changing showing this error

Comment: PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`projects` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")   
after changing showing this error

Comment: i have verified in my system .if you change $table->id(); to $table->bigIncrements('id'); in user migration it works fine.i have copied same migration from your question

Comment: in my system its not working what can i do?

Comment: once you delete all tables from database and run migration again.and can you post latest user migration code

Comment: $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: php artisan migrate:fresh 
i am using this command

Comment: delete all tables and run migration again

Comment: php artisan migrate:rollback and then run php aritsan migrate

Comment: do php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: the problem still exist?

Answer (score 0):

For the projects table, Laravel will figure it out itself.

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // $table->('id');
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('detail', 500)->nullable();
    $table->string('color', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('image', 22)->nullable();
    $table->string('logo', 22)->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')
        ->constrained()
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    
    $table->foreignId('product_id')
        ->constrained()
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`projects` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
This is The error now

Comment: why in your models do you use getUser() , i mean using get makes it an accessor , it is another thing

Comment: can you try user() and products() and also projects() , u need an s , this way laravel can understand the relations and guess the tables

Answer (score 0):

The issue is created in Laravel 8+, Usually, all of the answers concern with some older versions, I searched a lot but didn't get the problem of solution for the 8.4x version, And finally I tried different things to fix this issue and now after trying multiple things I find out the solution.
Try to change these files Product.php and Project.php file. 100% it will work for you.

**Product table (product.php)**

```
  public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('detail');
    $table->string('color');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('logo');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();//Change this line of Code
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')- 
    >onDelete('cascade');
   });
}
```

**Project table (project.php)**

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
   // $table->('id');
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
   $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
   $table->string('detail', 500)->nullable();
   $table->string('color', 255)->nullable();
   $table->string('image', 22)->nullable();
   $table->string('logo', 22)->nullable();
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index(); //Change this line of Code
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->nullable()->index();//Change this line of Code
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')- 
   >onDelete('cascade');
   $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')- 
   >onDelete('cascade');
   $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
   $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very easy, you need read and learn more about relation query build and table pivot many to many

example project and user

```
Schema::create('projects_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
});

 php artisan make:migration create_projects_user_table --create=projects_user
```

is very import search the create tables corrument to use

check is in Spanish please your search in English alternative
[youtube relation many to many](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2kHe8noduU&t=3s)